# Anyone see the Jenkins Parameterized Build Plugin Remove Build Steps from FreeStyle job Config?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We use parameterized build plugin and job config history plugin.  After several parameterized executions a build step vanished from the config causing checkout to fail and the job to fail.

Have you seen the parameterized build plugin remove steps when it should not?

Comment: Have you removed or disabled any plugins? Is the XML for the plugin still in the config XML http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131114/where-does-jenkins-store-configuration-files-for-the-jobs-it-runs

Comment: Nope.  We didn't change a think.  we use jenkins job builder but there was no publish. It looks like parameterized build plugin rewrites the job config and that sometimes it changes more than expected

Comment: The removal was a shell step

Comment: It was user error.  A user was configuring the job manually and not clicking on Build with params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User error.  My users were clicking on configure button and not "Build with Params"