# Where are Jenkins Jobs located in Linux Directory

Tags: jenkins

On a Linux Jenkins build, when a job is built and ran on an linux agent, where are the jobs stored?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does Jenkins store configuration files for the jobs it runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131114/where-does-jenkins-store-configuration-files-for-the-jobs-it-runs)

Comment: When a job is run on an agent, it's job details are still stored on the master.

Comment: If I wanted to remove a corrupt job, will I need to remove from Master and Agent? I was under the impression that jobs get stored on the Agent as well.

Comment: For a standard installation, details of the job are stored at /var/lib/jenkins/jobs. If there is a corrupt job, you will have to remove it from the master. But if you are on Slave/Agent machine and want to access the details pertaining to a job you can use either REST call or jenkins-cli. If you can mention what exactly is the problem than a more appropriate answer can be given

Answer (score 0):

I run jenkins inside a docker alpine container
and i can find jobs in /var/jenkins_home/jobs